# Compiling one sheet with data from multiple files

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to build a new table using data from multiple different ones, with the same layout. 
I have found and used a macro that takes me 50% of the way. But now im stuck.

At the moment I'm using three loops to check the files for information i want to copy and data is copied onto new lines.
**Result right now:**
**Row 1** Column X: Value A
**Row 2** Column X: Value B
**Row 3** Column X: Value C

Where X is the same column as the data is represented in in the source file.

**Goal format**
**Row 1** Column A: Value A
**Row 1** Column B: Value B
**Row 1** Column C: Value C

**This is my code:**

```
Sub RetrieveDataToThisWB(wb As String)
Dim ActiveWB As Workbook
Dim Rng As Range, ExtractRng As Range, c As Range
Dim DatRow As Long

Set ActiveWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=wb, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)


With ActiveWB.Sheets(2)
    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 26))
    Set ExtractRng = FindAll(Rng, "*Value A*")

If Not ExtractRng Is Nothing Then
    For Each c In ExtractRng

        If c.Row > DatRow Then
            ExportRow = ExportRow + 1

            Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(ExportRow, 1), Sheet1.Cells(ExportRow, 25)).Value = _
                .Range(.Cells(c.Row, 1), .Cells(c.Row, 25)).Value
            Sheet1.Cells(ExportRow, 27).Value = ActiveWB.Name
            Sheet1.Cells(ExportRow, 28).Value = ActiveWB.FullName
            Sheet1.Cells(ExportRow, 29).Value = Now()
            DatRow = c.Row
        End If
    Next c
End If
End With
With ActiveWB.Sheets(2)
    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 26))
    Set ExtractRng = FindAll(Rng, "*Value B*")

If Not ExtractRng Is Nothing Then
    For Each c In ExtractRng

        If c.Row > DatRow Then
            ExportRow = ExportRow + 1

            Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(ExportRow, 1), Sheet1.Cells(ExportRow, 25)).Value = _
                .Range(.Cells(c.Row, 1), .Cells(c.Row, 25)).Value
            Sheet1.Cells(ExportRow, 27).Value = ActiveWB.Name
            Sheet1.Cells(ExportRow, 28).Value = ActiveWB.FullName
            Sheet1.Cells(ExportRow, 29).Value = Now()
            DatRow = c.Row
        End If
    Next c
End If
End With
With ActiveWB.Sheets(2)
    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 26))
    Set ExtractRng = FindAll(Rng, "*Value C*")

If Not ExtractRng Is Nothing Then
    For Each c In ExtractRng

        If c.Row > DatRow Then
            ExportRow = ExportRow + 1

            Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(ExportRow, 1), Sheet1.Cells(ExportRow, 25)).Value = _
                .Range(.Cells(c.Row, 1), .Cells(c.Row, 25)).Value
            Sheet1.Cells(ExportRow, 27).Value = ActiveWB.Name
            Sheet1.Cells(ExportRow, 28).Value = ActiveWB.FullName
            Sheet1.Cells(ExportRow, 29).Value = Now()
            DatRow = c.Row
        End If
    Next c
End If
End With
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Your question/issue is unclear - 'I'm stuck' doesn't help us help you.

Comment: Sorry sir, question is how can i instead of exporting / adding rows to my new sheet add only cells. So each 3 loops just fills in cells on same row. maybe i've taken water over my head with this...